# kendo grid not loading data webforms

Tags: c#, webforms, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a lot of difficulty getting kendoGrid to bind to JSON data from a web method in an ASPX page. I keep getting the infinite spinner. The JSON is coming down from the ajax call. I dont know why its not binding to the grid. Here is my JS.

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    columns: [
           {
               field: "ClientName",
               title: "ClientName"

           }],
    dataSource: {
        type: 'json',
        serverPaging: true,
        schema: {
            data: 'd'
        },
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ServiceMonitoring.aspx/GetGridInformation',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: '',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    serverPaging: true,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        options.success(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    },
    height: 200,
    pageSize: 10


});
```

Comment: Try opening the page `ServiceMonitoring.aspx/GetGridInformation` and check that the server is returning data. If so, check that the format is the expected. BTW: Why do you use AJAX for loading the content and not just provide the URL?

Answer (score 1):

I knw this is a bit too late for you but try using

data: JSON.parse(d)

Hope this will help others who face this problem.

Thanks.